# Designing database for storing a 5 step dynamic form with specific data and some foreign keys

Tags: database-design

I've a 5 step form which is contained of multiple data field (about 10-12 field per step) and some of these data are foreign keys to another tables.

A solution to store this form from customer is to create tables for each step. But I think it is not such a good solution for a dynamic view to storing this form.

May you please help me what is the best design to deal with this question to store such this form?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend against blindly making a table for each form. I have seen such a design and it often does not make for a good design. Forms are designed to make data collection efficient, which can lead to a variety of problems in your schema. For example, you may have a question on your form that says "Marital status: Single, go to page 2, Married, go to page 3, etc.". You would end up with a SINGLE table, MARRIED table, etc.

Take all the fields in all the forms and try to group them into related facts. Work on identifying facts that may be sometimes exist or associative.

For example, every person has a name, a birth date, and eye color (though could be NONE if they lost their eyes or have a genetic issue). Not everyone has a college education and that could be a many-to-many relationship that has a mediating table that associates a user with a school along with such facts as start/stop date and degree attained. Note that the associative table can document different degree programs from primary education to PhD. Same concept with employer.

As you make those groupings, the tables and views should become apparent.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I checked a way that I can store the data using a `json` format and use a parser function in SQL in order to manipulate data.